# Animate a button as music plays

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I want to implement a play/pause button which is filling up, as the music is played. My first try was to create a timer which fires at 20 FPS (every 50ms) and call `View.invalidate()` on my button. The button itself had a customer `onDraw(...)` method which would, only statically for now, draw a bitmap to the canvas.

However, then running this in the simulator (I use GenyMotion) I immediately noticed that the sounds is jiggling, as if the CPU couldn't handle it.

I am a beginner in Android, so before experimenting in different way I would like to know, what is the recommended approach to animate a button as the music plays?

- Using a timer?
- Somehow using an animation?
- Can I speed up drawing? I will need to draw a masked and an unmasked bitmap, so these might be somehow CPU intense operations.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions I would like to give:

- Always preload bitmaps/images before animation. Loading resources on the fly can affect performance.
- Use Thread to perform operations.
- The best way to handle the above 2, is to use [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)
- [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) is another way for performing timer tasks using `handler.postDelayed()`

There is a beautiful sample code from Android on "How to make simple native games using SurfaceView", using threads and pre-loading bitmaps, called  [LunarLander](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-2.3.7_r1/samples/LunarLander).

If you look at [LunarView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-2.3.7_r1/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.java) code, they are using thread named `LunarThread` which is created on constructor of `LunarView` and started with the [surface is created](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceCreated%28android.view.SurfaceHolder%29).

It's inside the `LunarThread` they are performing all heavy task even drawing (inside thread's run method).

Basic OverView of LunarView:

- On constructor, creates thread `LunarThread`, which preloads bitmaps and perform related tasks
- When surface is created, starts the thread. Thread continuously runs/ gets paused, until the boolean flag `mRun` value is changed.
- Inside run method, it gets the canvas from surfaceView, locks and draw everything onto canvas for that frame, and un-locks.
- Its draws all time,till `mRun` value changed or when surface is destroyed(stops the thread, inside `surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` method)

Use SurfaceView, you will see difference.

Comment: The Problem is, a SurfaceView (with a transparent background) does not at all integrate nicely into the view hierarchy. I will have to discard my SurfaceView-based implementation...

Comment: What I have in my mind is: SurfaceView draws nothing, it gives you the blank canvas. If you have to draw a View by yourself, `SurfaceView` is the best choice than overriding `onDraw()`, such that we can avoid all pre-onDraw operations of a normal View. And you can use `Thread`, for `onDraw` you need UI thread.